# iOS 9 ATS Failing even with AllowInsecureHTTPLoads & Allow Arbitrary Loads

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, app-transport-security

I've tried ever solution that I have seen so far, and nothing has worked.

From what I understand, by putting Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES in your App Transport Security Settings of my info.plist file, it should turn off ALL ATS.

Even with that, I get `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

If I check my server with:

```
nscurl -ats-diagnostics --verbose https://apps-test.mydomain.com
```

ALL tests PASS!

If I try the TLSTool to check my server's settings, I get the following:

```
mac08:bin brent$ TLSTool s_client -connect apps-test.mydomain.com:443
*  input stream did open
* output stream did open
* output stream has space
* protocol: TLS 1.2
* cipher: RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* trust result: unspecified
* certificate info:
*   0 rsaEncryption 2048 sha256-with-rsa-signature '*.mydomain.com'
*   1 rsaEncryption 2048 sha256-with-rsa-signature 'Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2'
*   2 rsaEncryption 2048 sha256-with-rsa-signature 'Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2'
```

I wrote a simple iOS app that simply tries to do the following upon running...

```
NSString *url = @"https://apps-test.cticore.com/Home";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I have my App Transport Security Settings set to Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES

I also turned on NSURLConnection dubugging.  It gave me the following information:

```
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:1] 08:24:09.547 {
    LoaderWhatToDo
        Request: <CFURL 0x7cb74030 [0xd25098]>{string = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
    CachePolicy: 0
       WhatToDo: originload
    CreateToNow: 0.00942s
    } [1:1]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:2] 08:24:09.549 {
    AddCookies Continue: request GET https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home HTTP/1.1
           HTTPProtocol: Task: 7c87a8c0
    } [1:2]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:3] 08:24:09.550 {
    DiskCookieStorage Construction: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /Users/brent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/013D0A33-776E-4E2A-9C55-304C7D907E9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D457292-BD0C-4F46-B141-6E600FF618ED/Library/Cookies/com.MyDomain.gas2.SSLTest.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                         Accessing: <CFURL 0x7cb6b700 [0xd25098]>{string = file:///Users/brent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/013D0A33-776E-4E2A-9C55-304C7D907E9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D457292-BD0C-4F46-B141-6E600FF618ED/Library/Cookies/com.MyDomain.gas2.SSLTest.binarycookies, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
                              Path: /Users/brent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/013D0A33-776E-4E2A-9C55-304C7D907E9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D457292-BD0C-4F46-B141-6E600FF618ED/Library/Cookies/com.MyDomain.gas2.SSLTest.binarycookies
                    Read from disk: <0 cookies in 0 domains>
                             Dirty: NO
                           Writing: NO
                            Policy: 2
    } [1:3]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:4] 08:24:09.550 {
    DiskCookieStorage Journaling On: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /Users/brent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/013D0A33-776E-4E2A-9C55-304C7D907E9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D457292-BD0C-4F46-B141-6E600FF618ED/Library/Cookies/com.MyDomain.gas2.SSLTest.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                               File: <CFURL 0x7be766e0 [0xd25098]>{string = file:///Users/brent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/013D0A33-776E-4E2A-9C55-304C7D907E9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D457292-BD0C-4F46-B141-6E600FF618ED/Library/Cookies/com.MyDomain.gas2.SSLTest.binarycookies, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
    } [1:4]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:5] 08:24:09.550 {
    Protocol Enqueue: request GET https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home HTTP/1.1
             Request: <CFURLRequest 0x7cb63780 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
             Message: GET https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home HTTP/1.1
    } [1:5]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:6] 08:24:09.961 {
    Client Cert Requested
    } [1:6]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:7] 08:24:09.961 {
    Authentication Challenge
       Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Challenge: challenge space https://apps-test.MyDomain.com:443/, ClientCertificateRequested (Hash 9b9ca083)
    } [1:7]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:8] 08:24:09.961 {
    Use Credential
        Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Credential: null
    } [1:8]
Feb  1 08:24:09  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:9] 08:24:09.962 {
     touchConnection
              Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Timeout Interval: 60.000 seconds
    } [1:9]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:10] 08:24:09.962 {
    Peer certificate
    Subject Sum: *.MyDomain.com
        Summary: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    } [1:10]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:11] 08:24:10.072 {
    Authentication Challenge
       Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Challenge: challenge space https://apps-test.MyDomain.com:443/, ServerTrustEvaluationRequested (Hash 9b9ca083)
    } [1:11]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:12] 08:24:10.072 {
    Use Credential
        Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Credential: null
    } [1:12]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:13] 08:24:10.072 {
     touchConnection
              Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
    Timeout Interval: 60.000 seconds
    } [1:13]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:14] 08:24:10.073 {
    Response Error
    Request: <CFURLRequest 0x7cb63780 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
      Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=1, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7e173fa0>, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x7c96a670 [0xd25098]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
                0 : <cert(0x7cb624b0) s: *.MyDomain.com i: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2>
             )}}
    } [1:14]
Feb  1 08:24:10  SSLTest[70323] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:15] 08:24:10.074 {
               Did Fail
                 Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x7c878af0 [0xd25098]> {url = https://apps-test.MyDomain.com/Home, cs = 0x0}
                  Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=1, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7e173fa0>, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x7c96a670 [0xd25098]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
                            0 : <cert(0x7cb624b0) s: *.MyDomain.com i: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2>
                         )}}
    init to origin load: 0.010781s
             total time: 0.53556s
            total bytes: 0
    } [1:15]
```

I can see that it is failing, but I can't figure out what I can do to make it NOT fail!

Shouldn't turning off all of the ATS make anything pass?

Is this all caused by our Go Daddy certificate not using the proper cipher?

Why do ALL TLS checks pass via the command-line on my Mac, but trying to run via my super-simple App, I cannot connect.

I realize that this is a long post, but I have tried everything that I could find to get around this issue, yet nothing has worked.  Help.

UPDATE:

I can get my Swift example working if I Allow Arbitrary Loads and add the following to my NSURLSessionDelegate

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

    var disposition: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition = .PerformDefaultHandling
    var credential: NSURLCredential?

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential
        credential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    } else {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
            disposition = .CancelAuthenticationChallenge
        } else {
            credential = session.configuration.URLCredentialStorage?.defaultCredentialForProtectionSpace(challenge.protectionSpace)

            if credential != nil {
                disposition = .UseCredential
            }
        }
    }

    completionHandler(disposition, credential)
}
```

However, this solution is LESS than ideal because I would like to get ATS working properly with my existing server.

Does anyone know what the steps would be to actually fix things on my server side so that ATS will work properly?

Comment: Did you (correctly) include the intermediate certificates? What is the output of `openssl s_client -connect domain:443 -showcerts`?

Comment: Also, wouldn't you have a redirect somewhere in there? What does `curl -v url` say?